# Simple solitaire

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple solitaire in wich you get a random number of card heaps with a random number of cards in ex. heap1: 4 cards, heap2 5 cards and so on.
Lets say we have four heaps with values 4, 5, 7, 1. 
Now what is done is that one card is removed from each heap to create a new one.
So the next step would look like this 4, 5, 7, 1 -> 3, 4, 6, 4.
The solitaire is finished when it reaches a stable number ex.
5, 3, 2 -> 4, 2, 1, 3 -> 3, 1, 2 ,4... now we will always get the same four values if the numbers are sorted.

How would this be done in the best way? I have some basic knowledge in programming but 
nothing advanced.

So far i have tried this but it does not work out well, i don't know how to make the loop
stop at a stable number.

```
while len(y) > 1:
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i] -= 1
    y = [x for x in y if x != 0]
    y.append(len(y))
    y.sort()
    print(y)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this solitaire game and I'm afraid I don't really follow your explanation, is there a write-up of it somewhere you could link to? Also are you looking to make a playable game, or have the program play the game itself?

Comment: The only interaction is choosing the number of heaps and how many cards in each heap, max 52 carsd total min 2 cards. i'm sorry but i dont have a write-up.

Comment: @Sergei if this is homework, please tag it [tag:homework]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual cards (colors, faces) do not matter at all since all you model is a number of heaps?

Use a list for the setup, integers to represent the heaps, and the `random` module to generate the initial configuration. Programming the game logic should be rather straight-forward.

---

*UPDATE*

You're code is a good start.  To make things easier, consider breaking it up into separate functions.  E.g.:

```
def next_configuration(y):
    """Take a configuration of heaps and remove one card from each
    heap to create a new heap.
    """
    new_y = [x - 1 for x in y if x > 1]
    new_y.append(len(y))
    new_y.sort(reverse=True)
    return new_y
```

Now you can test if the function does what it is supposed to do:

```
>>> next_configuration([5, 1, 3, 2])
[4, 4, 2, 1]
```

To play it to the end, generate the next configuration until the current configuration does not change any more:

```
config = generate_initial_configuration()
for i in range(max_rounds):
    new_config = next_configuration(config)
    if new_config == config:
        break
    config = new_config
```

Comment: Except I don't actually think he wants to return the sorted version? His examples aren't sorted.

Comment: Also, you'll hit cycles almost every time instead of a single repeating state. You should detect those too.

Comment: @agf: This answer was not meant to give a complete solution but only some hints to get the OP started.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
def step(list):
    new_list = [x-1 for x in list if (x-1) > 0] #You remove one from each heap
    new_list.append(len(list)) #Now add the new heap
    if sorted(new_list) == sorted(list):
        return new_list, True
    else:
        return new_list, False
```

Then you can call the method like:

```
new_config, is_done = step(list)
```

until is_done is true. I hope you understand my ideea.

Comment: There's a bug in line 2.  `len(new_list)` is not the number of cards removed if one of the heaps was a single card.